# npm link recreates .nvm directory

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I removed nvm by following the instructions in the nvm removal guide (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#removal) but whenever I call `npm link` in any of my node projects, .nvm directory gets recreated. I have no traces of nvm in my .zshrc file or .bash_profile and when I call `brew uninstall nvm`, I get `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/nvm`.

I want to get rid of nvm completely and use nodenv instead.

Whenever I go to a node project and call `npm link`, I see

`/Users/{username}/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/{project-name} -> /Users/{username}/Developer/{project-name}`

I have no idea why it decides to use nvm with version `v8.9.1`. Does anyone have any ideas?

I even reinstalled node and npm but it's still happening.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check your ~/.npmrc? If you found nvm related content, you need to delete it as well.